# how to package a django project?

Tags: python, django, package, pypi

How can i package a project so that i can just call some function that runs the project?

I know how to package a django app, but my question is how to package a django project.

Currently i have my project on an internal pypi server and can pull it down using:

```
pip install [project]
```

but then to use it i have to go into my site-packages and then the package just so i can run

```
./manage.py ....
```

Or am i just better off checking out the project and pip installing the apps?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy to a production environment?

Comment: yes i will be, currently im just testing deployment in a virtual enviroment

Comment: Have you read about wsgi? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Comment: I am using [gunicorn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/) instead of wsgi (due to the fact gunicorn handles asynch workers), but as it says (if im reading it right) is you need to give a full path. I run it using './manage.py run_gunicorn ....'

Comment: Hmm.  I guess I misunderstood the question a bit, in that I thought you wanted to automate the launch of the app (in production, manage.py is pretty irrelevant).  In our projects we typically have a chef script check out the code, pip install dependencies, and then run uwsgi pointed (with full path) to the checkout location.

Comment: thats what im thinking i may have to do, just check out the project, im just wondering if i could pip install it

Answer (score 2):

One way, is to create a package using your distros package management system. At my shop, we use Ubuntu's aptitude. So package our software as a .deb using CMake.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best way to do it, but you can use `distribute` to generate wrapper scripts for you: http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question with [my own project](https://github.com/danielquinn/paperless).  The solution, as the community around the project arrived at, was to package it in a number of ways for different platforms, but *not* as a PyPi module.

In order of popularity, my project is typically installed via:

- Docker instance: `docker pull <project-name> && docker-compose up`
- Cloning the git repo: `git clone <url> && ./project/scripts/do-the-thing`
- Vagrant: `vagrant up`

If there was more support in the group, I suppose it would make sense to roll out a `.deb`, `.ebuild`, and `.rpm`, but at this stage, people seem more-or-less happy with the above.